# Plugin with Observer Pattern

Tags: php, plugins, observer-pattern

I have recently look into observable pattern and I understand how things work and the concept. I also played with it in my application but I want to find out how to use it when you want to make a plugin in a php application, because that was my main purpose.

I haven't found any decent example until now. I want to understand the concept of making plugin with observable and also a good and easy example would be nice.

By making a plugin I mean to have a standard application and want to do some particular stuff for every client, because not all the clients ask the same things I can't give them all the same application, so the ideas so to make a standard application and configure it for every client and I understand that something like that is called to make a plugin and It can be done with observer.

Answer (score 0):

Observer/Observable pattern would be a good fit if you want to implement some kind of *custom triggers/actions* based on user or application/service actions.

For example, an identity/authentication service might implement a pluggable architecture using some kind of *observer* to let third-party plug-ins do something when some user authenticates, or some user is registered...

Also it should work in the UI, because you might be able to show a menu or add some visual component based on user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a very free plugin based application, you might want to do a slightly different version of this.

Implement a centralized event control.

Each Plugin (serving as your controllers) registers there to be notified for certain events.

Now if you want to access some functionality, just dispatch a specific event through that central event control. You no longer need to know what plugin will respond to your event, you only need to know the interface of said event and the form of response you will get.

Now multiple plugins can register on a event, overriding or extending the results of other plugins. Or just allow completely new events.

This application structure takes a bit of patience to properly create all needed classes, but the end product is extremely decoupled -> flexible. Think of it as a form of MVC where the controller(s) dont need to know each other, they just know where to ask in a very generic form.

(I heard Zend2 tries a similar approach?)

Comment: Thank you that make some things clear for me but I am not so advanced in application web because i start recently and I still can't understand some things,could you give me a small exemple of a path from when you want some functionality  to add her in your standard application,to see the order of things  ?

Comment: This would exceed this chat by far. You should really look for some books on this subject. I would go for the "Head First" Series, they have a very nice and easy book about patterns.
http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfdp/